# Tool similar to Dynamic code evolution with java 7 support

Tags: virtual-machine, java-7, dcevm

I have been using the dynamic code evaluation for dynamic loading of my changed classes in my Jboss server ,

I have found this tool very helpful and interesting , but it have a problem that it works with jdk 1.6 , but As i am trying to use java 7 in my project it fails .

Can anyone suggest similar type of tool with java7 support

Answer (score 5):

I suggest using... the Dynamic Code Evolution VM for Java 7 :) The DCEVM web site is not up to date and the version available for download there doesn't work with the latest versions of Java 7. For some time the [Mercurial repository](https://ssw.jku.at/hg/dcevm) contained a more recent version and it has been eventually forked on [Github](https://dcevm.github.io) where binaries for Windows and Linux are provided. On Debian/Ubuntu DCEVM is also available after installing the openjdk-7-jre-dcevm package.

Comment: Above binary works only for Win32, but is there a 64 bit version, available?

Comment: I haven't compiled a 64 bit version but you can give it a try. A 32 bit VM is usually good enough for developing.

Comment: I tried but found to be not working.  If you are the author, could you publish for 64 bit also?

Comment: Try here: http://dcevm.nentjes.com/ if you want a 64 bit version. It works well for me.